# DB2 - vba script crashes at "If RS.BOF And RS.EOF Then"

Tags: excel, vba, db2, adodb

We have a couple of loading scripts that upload data from Excel(work is done in the Excelfiles) to our iSeries DB2-database. They have worked flawless for a couple of years. So far so good. Since january a second person have taken over running the scripts and now they don't work for that person.  For me, no problem, works flawlessly. As soon as the second person tries to run the program, Excel crashes at the first If in the code:

> If RS.BOF And RS.EOF Then

It is sometimes possible to step through the program but not always. Stepping through until RS.Open reveals nothing wrong with the BOF and EOF parameters.

If I could I would stop using Excel for this kind of thing and move everything to R. But that's not possible, so I have to find whats wrong with the script. My only guess so far is that it's something with the drivers and so my question is. In respect to VBA connection strings and ISeries ODBC Drivers, is there something I should change in the code?

Code that use this layout and just open and close a recordset has been proven to work for all of us. Might be that I just have to rewrite the programs from scratch. Not an impossible feat but rather something that I would avoid if I can.

```
Dim cnDB As New ADODB.Connection
Dim RS As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim conStr As String


    'Open a connection to ISeries
    conStr = "Driver={ISeries Access ODBC Driver};System=oursys;Uid=kUid;Pwd=kPass;Library = ourschema"
    Set cnDB = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set RS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    cnDB.ConnectionString = conStr
    cnDB.Open


    SQL_str = "Select * from TEST.TESTTABLE"


    Debug.Print SQL_str

    RS.Open SQL_str, cnDB, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic



    If RS.BOF And RS.EOF Then
```

Comment: So do you have a working machine (that you use), and a failing machine (used by the new person)? If that is the case, you do not have a programming matter for stackoverflow and you have a problem determination matter , to systematically eliminate each and every difference between working and failing...

Comment: @mao Well, I do belive there might be a problem with how I declare drivers in the code and that's a programming problem. Do I need to declare drivers at all for example? Do declaring drivers the way I do add unnecessary complication? Placing restrictions on the odbc-configuration that might become a problem if we have subtle differences?

Comment: If the Db2 driver is from the same supplier, same major version, same configuration,  and the VBA version the same, then you should not need to change code. If there are *differences* either in versions or configurations then *eliminate* them one by one to see what needs changing.

Comment: What do you do after this condition(RS.BOF And RS.EOF)? In this case, it is known that an error is issued.

Comment: In the VBA editor, look in Tools > References and see if any of the references are marked as "MISSING:". Even though the code uses late binding - `CreateObject` - to create the connection and recordset that are actually used, it uses early binding - `Dim cnDB As New ADODB.Connection` etc - to declare them and to instantiate them initially before the late binding re-instantiates them. Therefore, it does have a dependency on a reference to some version of "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects"

Comment: @Dy.Lee An execute command. Either an insert or in case the logic is false. Delete first, insert  after that.

Comment: @barrowc No, our references are the same, as is our version of office 365. There is a difference in Iseries drivers (I have newer) so our IT-dept are looking at that.